# Php Array (few) foreach get values

Tags: php, arrays

Doing simple ftp viewer in php:

i've got a function that returns arrays with file_name.

I do (in the end of my function) `print_r($files);` and this is out put

```
Array ( [0] => task_manager.zip [1] => 1086237 [2] => zip ) Array ( [0] => asd.zip [1] => 1086237 [2] => zip [3] => fonts/some_file.zip [4] => 959224 [5] => zip )
```

As you can see i get arrays, and this is perfect but then i want to get file_name, file_size & file_extension and I get fail:

p.s - `ListFiles` - is my function name, `('fonts/')` - folder where i find files

```
foreach (ListFiles('fonts/') as $key=>$file){
    echo 'file_name = '.$file."<br/>";
}
```

and I get:

```
file_name = task_manager.zip
file_name = 1086237
file_name = zip
file_name = fonts/some_file.zip
file_name = 959224
file_name = zip
```

which actually is wrong, because i want do it in one line, something like this:

WHAT I WANT (NEAR THE PERFECT WAY) TO DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS:

in php:

```
foreach (ListFiles('fonts/') as $key=>$file){
    echo 'file_name = '.$file[0].'file_size = '.$file[1].'file_ext = '.$file[2].'<br/>';
}
```

in html:

```
file_name = task_manager.zip, file_size = 1086237, file_ext = zip
file_name = some_file.zip, file_size = 959224, file_ext = zip
```

UPDATE: MY ListFiles function

```
function ListFiles($dir) {
    if($dh = opendir($dir)) {

                //This data I get from form
        $allowedExts = array();
        if(isset($_POST['exts'])){
            for ( $i=0; $i < count($_POST['exts']); $i++ ){
                array_push($allowedExts, $_POST['exts'][$i]);
            }
        } // end of this data

        $files = Array();
        $inner_files = Array();
        while($file = readdir($dh)) {
            if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file[0] != '.') {
                if(is_dir($dir . "/" . $file)) {
                    $inner_files = ListFiles($dir . "" . $file);
                    if(is_array($inner_files))
                        $files = array_merge($files, $inner_files); 
                } else {
                    if(in_array(end(explode('.', $file)), $allowedExts)){
                        $filesize = filesize('./'.$dir.$file);
                        $userfile_extn = substr($file, strrpos($file, '.')+1);
                        array_push($files, $dir . "/" . $file, $filesize, $userfile_extn);

                    }                
                }
            }
        }

        closedir($dh);
        return $files;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about showing the source code of your `ListFiles` function?

Comment: We need your `ListFiles()` function because there is a better way to setup your array for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Rewrite the `array_push($files, $dir . "/" . $file, $filesize, $userfile_extn);` line as `$files []= array($dir . "/" . $file, $filesize, $userfile_extn);`.

Comment: man, you are awesome:) I've made a stupid mistake and you foound it! NICE!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:

```
$files = ListFiles('fonts/');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i += 3){
    echo 'file_name = '.$files[$i].'file_size = '.$files[$i+1].'file_ext = '.$files[$i+2].'<br/>';
}
```

Better way:

http://pastie.org/4567820